# Attribute to change the color of the tab indicator

Tags: android, android-styles, viewpagerindicator

This problem is really driving me crazy.
I am using the viewpager indicator without any trouble, but I would like to change something on the final result:

[image: ViewPager screen]

I would like to change the color of the line from blue to green; obviously I would like to keep the same line color when a tab is selected. This is my style file:

```
<resources>


<style name="collection_field">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="collection_header" parent="collection_field">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>


<style name="CollectionTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>


</style>

<style name="Theme.Collection" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CollectionTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>
```

What attribute am I supposed to use to make this happens? Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create your own tab indicators then apply them using the `android:background` attribute in your `CollectionTabPageIndicator` style.

```
<style name="CollectionTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

The easiest way to create your own green indicators is to use the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

Once there, turn on the **Tab hairline style** and apply your **Tab indicator color**. Then download the `zip`, copy over all of your tab indicator resources into the appropriate drawable folders, and finally add it your style.

For reference, here's the default blue indicator [res/drawable/vpi__tab_indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/res/drawable/vpi__tab_indicator.xml#L17)